# Latency of requesting a object from S3 to EC2

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, latency

What's the latency to GET an object from S3 from an EC2 Instance.

For example, how many ms before the actual data stream for that object starts streaming back when requesting a object by it's full path.

- If the object exists on S3
- If the object does not exist and to send a 404

Latency, not Throughput.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think AWS makes guarantees about latency, but using S3 from EC2 is definitely going to be faster than doing it over the web. If you want to get an idea of how well S3 performs in practice, check out http://www.cloudstatus.com/. Unfortunately, that site only gives throughput statistics, but I figure you may be interested in that anyway. You may also be interested in their availability guarantee: http://aws.amazon.com/s3-sla/

Comment: Throughput I am not too worried about, the files are several kB in size except for a few exceptions, so the bottle neck I am worried about is the initial connection latency. 

Thanks.

Comment: cloudstatus link is broken. May want to consider accepting Dirk's answer instead.

Answer (score 47):

**In 2023**, p50 (median) latency measured in an `r6g.medium` instance (not too big, not too small) is 10 to 15ms, with outliers up to 60ms. You can use this utility to check it for yourself:

```
https://github.com/dvassallo/s3-benchmark
```

**Original (outdated) answer from 2009:**

We usually experience latency of around 200-300ms from EC2 to S3. It's much slower than you might expect.

Comment: Thanks, and you're right, I didn't expect it to be that high.

Comment: Worth noting this is a very old answer; I'm sure AWS team has done much work to improve that; within the same region I wouldn't expect the TTFB (time to first byte) to go beyond 30ms